# Message widget not filling frame using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, message, pack

I'm creating a simple user dialog window with a basic text on top and a tree view with one column below, that gives the user a couple of choices. A button at the bottom is used to confirm the selection.

Now I can't get the Message widget, which I use to display the instructions, to fill the Frame I've created for it. Meanwhile, the Treeview widget fills the Frame as I want it to.

Many proposed solutions on other StackOverflow questions state, that putting `my_message.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True)` should work. It doesn't in my case.. In a different scenario it is recommended to put `my_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`, which doesn't help either.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MessageBox(object):
    """ Adjusted code from StackOverflow #10057662. """

    def __init__(self, msg, option_list):

        root = self.root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("400x400")
        root.title('Message')
        self.msg = str(msg)
        frm_1 = tk.Frame(root)
        frm_1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X, ipadx=2, ipady=2)
        message = tk.Message(frm_1, text=self.msg)
        message.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X) # <------------------------------------ This doesn't show the desired effect!
        frm_1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.tree_view = ttk.Treeview(frm_1)
        self.tree_view.heading("#0", text="Filename", anchor=tk.CENTER)
        for idx, option in enumerate(option_list):
            self.tree_view.insert("", idx+1, text=option)
        self.tree_view.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=2, pady=2)



choice_msg = "Long Test string to show, that my frame is unfortunately not correctly filled from side to side, as I would want it to."
choices = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
test = MessageBox(choice_msg, choices)
test.root.mainloop()
```

I'm slowly going nuts, because I know that there is probably something very basic overruling the correct positioning of the widget, but I've been trying different StackOverflow solutions and browsing documentation for hours now with no luck.

Comment: The Message _does_ fill the frame in the x direction. You can see this by giving it a distinct background. Your problem is that the text isn't filling the widget.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley thank you for the hint, I knew it was something painstakingly obvious which I've overlooked..

Comment: @BryanOakley While the `Message` widget fills the space, the text itself does not. In my opinion, the sophisticated concept around the `width` and `aspect` options doesn't really help us. I ended up having to use a resize handler to implement a dynamic `width`. Please take a look at my answer if you find the time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set a width of `message` in the `tk.Message` constructor, something like this:

```
    message = tk.Message(frm_1, text=self.msg, width=400-10)  # 400 - is your window width
    message.pack()  # In that case you can delete <expand=True, fill=tk.X>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is a feature: The `Message` widget tries to lay out the text in one of two ways:

- according to an `aspect` (width-to-height ratio in percent)
- according to a maximum `width` (lines will be broken if longer)

Both of these goals seem not to cooperate well with the automatic resizing a `Message` widget experiences from a `grid` or `pack` layout manager. What can be done is to bind a handler to the resize event of the widget to adjusts the `width` option dynamically. Also, there are better options to use with the `pack` layout manager than shown in OP.

I derived an `AutoMessage` widget to get the event handler out of the way:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class AutoMessage(tk.Message):
    """Message that adapts its width option to its actual window width"""

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **options):
        tk.Message.__init__(self, parent, *args, **options)

        # The value 4 was found by experiment, it prevents text to be
        # displayed outside of the widget (exceeding the right border)
        self.padx = 4 + 2 * options.get("padx", 0)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_handler)

    def resize_handler(self, event):
        self.configure(width=event.width - self.padx)


class MessageBox(object):
    """Adjusted code from StackOverflow #10057662."""

    def __init__(self, msg, option_list):
        root = self.root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("400x400")
        root.title("Message")
        self.msg = str(msg)
        self.frm_1 = tk.Frame(root)
        self.frm_1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=2, pady=2)
        self.message = AutoMessage(self.frm_1, text=self.msg, anchor=tk.W)
        self.message.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.frm_1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.tree_view = ttk.Treeview(self.frm_1)
        self.tree_view.heading("#0", text="Filename", anchor=tk.CENTER)
        for idx, option in enumerate(option_list):
            self.tree_view.insert("", idx + 1, text=option)
        self.tree_view.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=2, pady=2)


choice_msg = "Long Test string to show, that my frame is unfortunately not correctly filled from side to side, as I would want it to."
choices = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
test = MessageBox(choice_msg, choices)
test.root.mainloop()
```